# Using value of array element in javascript function does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays

This batch does not work, although I put in all possible checks to know wthere a certain assignment does not come through:

```
alert("valorsumo = "+valorsumo);  // okay
for (j = 0; j <= "<?php echo $fVN ?>"; j++) {
  horp = valornbroj[j];
  alert("horp = "+horp);  // okay
  elcentoj[j] = Math.round(horp/valorsumo * 1000) / 10;  // percentage with one decimal
  alert("percentage = "+elcentoj[i]);  //  undefined !
```

The queer thing is that the same kind of code, met in a separate file produces the desired answer:

```
function het()  {     
  var nbroj = [],
  sumo = 3894,
  elcentoj = [];
  nbroj[0] = "290046";   
  elcentoj[0] = Math.round(nbroj[0]/sumo * 1000) / 10;
  alert("percentage = "+elcentoj[0]);  // okay
}
```

Am I blind? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try changing elcentoj[i] to elcentoj[j] :) Semi-blind :)

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
alert("percentage = "+elcentoj[i]);
```

I is not defined replace i with j

```
alert("percentage = "+elcentoj[j]);
```

So your loop will be  like this

```
for (j = 0; j <= "<?php echo $fVN ?>"; j++) {
  horp = valornbroj[j];
  alert("horp = "+horp);  // okay
  elcentoj[j] = Math.round(horp/valorsumo * 1000) / 10;  // percentage with one decimal
  alert("percentage = "+elcentoj[j]);  
}
```

Comment: Shame on me!
The wrong index hid the real mistake, which happily I found already: a variable was defined locally, within function het(), while it needed to be passed to another function.
Thank you !